# Gradient Descent algorithm for linear regression do not optmize the y-intercept parameter

Tags: python, algorithm, data-science, gradient-descent

I'm following Andrew Ng Coursera course on Machine Learning and I tried to implement the Gradient Descent Algorithm in Python. I'm having trouble with the y-intercept parameter because it doesn't look like to go to the best value. Here's my code:

```
# IMPORTS
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Acquiring Data
# Source: https://github.com/mattnedrich/GradientDescentExample
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

def cost_function(a, b, x_values, y_values):
    '''
    Calculates the square mean error for a given dataset
    with (x,y) pairs and the model y' = a + bx

    a: y-intercept for the model
    b: slope of the curve
    x_values, y_values: points (x,y) of the dataset
    '''
    data_len = len(x_values)
    total_error = sum([((a + b * x_values[i]) - y_values[i])**2
                       for i in range(data_len)])
    return total_error / (2 * float(data_len))


def a_gradient(a, b, x_values, y_values):
    '''
    Partial derivative of the cost_function with respect to 'a'

    a, b: values for 'a' and 'b'
    x_values, y_values: points (x,y) of the dataset
    '''
    data_len = len(x_values)
    a_gradient = sum([((a + b * x_values[i]) - y_values[i])
                      for i in range(data_len)])
    return a_gradient / float(data_len)


def b_gradient(a, b, x_values, y_values):
    '''
    Partial derivative of the cost_function with respect to 'b'

    a, b: values for 'a' and 'b'
    x_values, y_values: points (x,y) of the dataset
    '''
    data_len = len(x_values)
    b_gradient = sum([(((a + b * x_values[i]) - y_values[i]) * x_values[i])
                      for i in range(data_len)])
    return b_gradient / float(data_len)


def gradient_descent_step(a_current, b_current, x_values, y_values, alpha):
    '''
    Give a step in direction of the minimum of the cost_function using
    the 'a' and 'b' gradiants. Return new values for 'a' and 'b'.

    a_current, b_current: the current values for 'a' and 'b'
    x_values, y_values: points (x,y) of the dataset

    '''
    new_a = a_current - alpha * a_gradient(a_current, b_current, x_values, y_values)
    new_b = b_current - alpha * b_gradient(a_current, b_current, x_values, y_values)
    return (new_a, new_b)


def run_gradient_descent(a, b, x_values, y_values, alpha, precision, plot=False, verbose=False):
    '''
    Runs the gradient_descent_step function and updates (a,b) until
    the value of the cost function varies less than 'precision'.

    a, b: initial values for the point a and b in the cost_function
    x_values, y_values: points (x,y) of the dataset
    alpha: learning rate for the algorithm
    precision: value for the algorithm to stop calculation
    '''
    iterations = 0
    delta_cost = cost_function(a, b, x_values, y_values)

    error_list = [delta_cost]
    iteration_list = [0]

    # The loop runs until the delta_cost reaches the precision defined
    # When the variation in cost_function is small it means that the
    # the function is near its minimum and the parameters 'a' and 'b'
    # are a good guess for modeling the dataset.
    while delta_cost > precision:
        iterations += 1
        iteration_list.append(iterations)

        # Calculates the initial error with current a,b values
        prev_cost = cost_function(a, b, x_values, y_values)

        # Calculates new values for a and b
        a, b = gradient_descent_step(a, b, x_values, y_values, alpha)

        # Updates the value of the error
        actual_cost = cost_function(a, b, x_values, y_values)
        error_list.append(actual_cost)

        # Calculates the difference between previous and actual error values.
        delta_cost = prev_cost - actual_cost

    # Plot the error in each iteration to see how it decreases
    # and some information about our final results
    if plot:
        plt.plot(iteration_list, error_list, '-')
        plt.title('Error Minimization')
        plt.xlabel('Iteration',fontsize=12)
        plt.ylabel('Error',fontsize=12)
        plt.show()
    if verbose:
        print('Iterations = ' + str(iterations))
        print('Cost Function Value = '+ str(cost_function(a, b, x_values, y_values)))
        print('a = ' + str(a) + ' and b = ' + str(b))

    return (actual_cost, a, b)
```

When I run the algorithm with:

```
run_gradient_descent(0, 0, data['x'], data['y'], 0.0001, 0.01)
```

I get (a = 0.0496688656535 and b = 1.47825808018)

But the best value for 'a' is around 7.9 (tried another resources for linear regression).

Also, if I change the initial guess for the parameter 'a' the algorithm simply try to adjust the parameter 'b'.

For example, if I set a = 200 and b = 0

```
run_gradient_descent(200, 0, data['x'], data['y'], 0.0001, 0.01)
```

I get (a = 199.933763331 and b = -2.44824996193)

I couldn't find anything wrong with the code and I realized that the problem is the initial guess for `a` parameter. See my own answer above where I defined a helper function to get a range for search some values for initial `a` guess.

Comment: I am working on the same problem than you, and... I'm stuck on the same step. I tried your program with my inputs : surprisingly, I have the same output with my program and yours. More than code-related problem, we might be forgetting something. If you have a way for me to contact you, we might try to solve this together.

Comment: I didn't find a way to send you direct messages here at SO. Also I'm not willing to disclose my email here :D Do you have any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete code for my Gradient Descent implementation could be found on my Github repository:
[Gradient Descent for Linear Regression](https://github.com/claudiocastello/learning_data_science/tree/master/GradientDescentLinearRegression)

Thinking about what @relay said that the Gradient Descent algorithm does not guarantee to find the global minima I tried to come up with an helper function to limit guesses for the parameter `a` in a certain search range, as follows:

```
def search_range(x, y, plot=False):
    '''
    Given a dataset with points (x, y) searches for a best guess for 
    initial values of 'a'.
    '''
    data_lenght = len(x)             # Total size of of the dataset
    q_lenght = int(data_lenght / 4)  # Size of a quartile of the dataset

    # Finding the max and min value for y in the first quartile
    min_Q1 = (x[0], y[0])
    max_Q1 = (x[0], y[0])

    for i in range(q_lenght):
        temp_point = (x[i], y[i])
        if temp_point[1] < min_Q1[1]:
            min_Q1 = temp_point
        if temp_point[1] > max_Q1[1]:
            max_Q1 = temp_point

    # Finding the max and min value for y in the 4th quartile
    min_Q4 = (x[data_lenght - 1], y[data_lenght - 1])
    max_Q4 = (x[data_lenght - 1], y[data_lenght - 1])

    for i in range(data_lenght - 1, data_lenght - q_lenght, -1):
        temp_point = (x[i], y[i])
        if temp_point[1] < min_Q4[1]:
            min_Q4 = temp_point
        if temp_point[1] > max_Q4[1]:
            max_Q4 = temp_point

    mean_Q4 = (((min_Q4[0] + max_Q4[0]) / 2), ((min_Q4[1] + max_Q4[1]) / 2))

    # Finding max_y and min_y given the points found above
    # Two lines need to be defined, L1 and L2.
    # L1 will pass through min_Q1 and mean_Q4
    # L2 will pass through max_Q1 and mean_Q4

    # Calculatin slope for L1 and L2 given m = Delta(y) / Delta (x)
    slope_L1 = (min_Q1[1] - mean_Q4[1]) / (min_Q1[0] - mean_Q4[0])
    slope_L2 = (max_Q1[1] - mean_Q4[1]) / (max_Q1[0] -mean_Q4[0])

    # Calculating y-intercepts for L1 and L2 given line equation in the form y = mx + b
    # Float numbers are converted to int because they will be used as range for itaration
    y_L1 = int(min_Q1[1] - min_Q1[0] * slope_L1)
    y_L2 = int(max_Q1[1] - max_Q1[0] * slope_L2)

    # Ploting L1 and L2
    if plot:
        L1 = [(y_L1 + slope_L1 * x) for x in data['x']]
        L2 = [(y_L2 + slope_L2 * x) for x in data['x']]

        plt.plot(data['x'], data['y'], '.')
        plt.plot(data['x'], L1, '-', color='r') 
        plt.plot(data['x'], L2, '-', color='r') 
        plt.title('Scatterplot of Sample Data')
        plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=12)
        plt.ylabel('y',fontsize=12)
        plt.show()

    return y_L1, y_L2
```

The idea is to run the gradient descent with guesses for `a` within the range given by search_range() function and get the minimum possible value for the cost_function(). The new way to run the gradient descente becomes:

```
def run_search_gradient_descent(x_values, y_values, alpha, precision, verbose=False):
    '''
    Runs the gradient_descent_step function and updates (a,b) until
    the value of the cost function varies less than 'precision'.

    x_values, y_values: points (x,y) of the dataset
    alpha: learning rate for the algorithm
    precision: value for the algorithm to stop calculation
    '''    
    from math import inf

    a1, a2 = search_range(x_values, y_values)

    best_guess = [inf, 0, 0]

    for a in range(a1, a2):

        cost, linear_coef, slope = run_gradient_descent(a, 0, x_values, y_values, alpha, precision)

        # Saving value for cost_function and parameters (a,b)        
        if cost < best_guess[0]:
            best_guess = [cost, linear_coef, slope]
    if verbose:        
        print('Cost Function = ' + str(best_guess[0]))
        print('a = ' + str(best_guess[1]) + ' and b = ' + str(best_guess[2]))

    return (best_guess[0], best_guess[1], best_guess[2])
```

Running the code

`run_search_gradient_descent(data['x'], data['y'], 0.0001, 0.001, verbose=True)`

I've got:

`Cost Function = 55.1294483959
a = 8.02595996606 and b = 1.3209768383`

For comparison, using the linear regression from scipy.stats it returned

`a = 7.99102098227and b = 1.32243102276`

Answer (score 1):

Gradient descent does not guarantee to find global optimum. Your chances of finding the global optimum depend on your starting value. To get the real values of the parameters, first I solved the least squares problem which guarantees global minimum.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv',header=-1)

x,y = data[0],data[1]

from scipy.stats import linregress

linregress(x,y)
```

This results in following statistics:

```
LinregressResult(slope=1.32243102275536, intercept=7.9910209822703848, rvalue=0.77372849988782377, pvalue=3.855655536990139e-21, stderr=0.109377979589804)
```

Thus `b = 1.32243102275536` and `a = 7.9910209822703848`. Given this, using your code I solved the problem a couple of times using randomized starting values `a` and `b`:

```
a,b = np.random.rand()*10,np.random.rand()*10

print("Initial values of parameters: ")

print("a=%f\tb=%f" % (a,b))

run_gradient_descent(a, b,x,y,1e-4,1e-2)
```

Here is the solution that I got:

```
Initial values of parameters: 
a=6.100305  b=2.606448

Iterations = 21
Cost Function Value = 55.2093808263
a = 6.07601889437 and b = 1.36310312751
```

Therefore, it seems like the reason that you cannot get close to minimum is because of choice of your initial parameter values. You will see it yourself as well, if you put `a` and `b` obtained from least squares into your gradient descent algorithm, it will iterate only for one time and stay where it is.

Somehow, at some point `delta_cost > precision` is `True` and it stops there considering it a local optimum. If you decrease your `precision` and if you run it long enough then you might be able to find the global optimum.

Comment: I'm thinking about implementing something to test some initial values for `a` and `b`. From what I remember, the cost_function in this case has only a global minima so it's not possible to get stuck in another local minima. I think there's something wrong in the code but I couldn't see it yet. Thanks BTW.

Comment: I changed the answer, please see above.

Comment: Did your solution works? I tried here and got the same problem. I think adding this constant before the derivatives won't change the solution. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to check what a derivative is and try to take the derivatives of the error function yourself. Those are not just some random constants. Having wrong derivatives will change your results.

Comment: Don't be so offended. I know what a derivative is and where the 2 came from. Before writing the code I did the derivatives with paper and pen. If you see my cost function you will notice that it's being divided by 2 which cancel the 2 from the derivatives with respect to a and b. I tried your solution because maybe I was missing something but it worked the same way. There were no behavior change in the optimization and the y-intercept keeps not changing properly to converge to the right value. Did you tried the code? It worked for you? Please, post your code and results here if it worked. Tks!

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tried your code and my code to run the algorithm with these parameters:
`a, b = run_gradient_descent(100, 0, data['x'], data['y'], 0.0001, 0.01)`

And got the results below:
**Your code**
`Iterations = 10
Cost Function Value = 429.749679724
a = 99.9835179353 and b = -0.485163331546`

**My Code**
`Iterations = 18
Cost Function Value = 214.886670719
a = 99.9842575402 and b = -0.482874616246`

With your code I got less iteratios and a higher value for cost_function. For my code I got more iterations and a lower value. But `a` and `b` almost the same.

Comment: I tested your code and added results to the answer. Please see the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. These days I got busy but I'm almost finishing an implementation to set a range to search randomly for the best solution in that reduced range. I'm posting it here in the next few days. Thanks again!